# All Sprites are moved to same coordinates?

Tags: python, pygame

The code below is basically a test for me to get to know Sprites and Groups. It is supposed to create 10 instances of the `Ball` class, and then randomly position and move each, and bounce them around the screen. The problem is, whilst they all get positioned independently, for some reason they all seem to inherit the same coordinates during the loop and so there appears to be only 1 ball bouncing around.

```
import pygame, sys, random

pygame.init()

size = width, height = 640, 400
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

class Ball(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    image = pygame.image.load('assets/ball.gif').convert()
    rect = image.get_rect()
    max_speed = 2
    speed = 0
    direction = [1, 1]

    def randomize(self):
        random.seed()
        self.rect.x = random.random() * width
        self.rect.y = random.random() * height
        self.speed = random.random() * self.max_speed
        print ('%s %s %s') % (self.rect.x, self.rect.y, self.speed)

    def update(self):
        if self.rect.left < 0:
            self.direction[0] =  1
        if self.rect.right > width:
            self.direction[0] = -1
        if self.rect.top < 0:
            self.direction[1] =  1
        if self.rect.bottom > height:
            self.direction[1] = -1

        self.rect.x += self.speed * self.direction[0]
        self.rect.y += self.speed * self.direction[1]

layers = pygame.sprite.LayeredUpdates()
black = 0, 0, 0
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

for i in range(0,10):
    ball = Ball()
    ball.randomize()
    layers.add(ball)

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: sys.exit()

    screen.fill(black)
    layers.update()
    layers.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(30)
```

Below is the output from `Ball.randomize()`:

```
454 317 0.268577946144
560 175 0.777246064841
446 161 1.71602882781
337 221 0.298744471713
9 122 1.19615176471
304 351 1.45267115709
255 397 0.478593408657
135 213 1.04660721161
96 26 0.758952705602
389 106 0.954778970584
```

I assume I'm not understanding how pygame.image works and that somehow Ball.image is actually the same object shared across all instances, however I don't really know how to prove it, nor how to resolve it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right, Ball.image is shared across all instances. So are all other variables, including rect and so on, because you created them at class scope -- this has nothing to do with pygame.

Add an `__init__` magic method to your class, similar to the following:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.rect = Ball.image.get_rect()
    self.speed = 0
    self.direction = [1, 1]
```

And remove the corresponding assignments at class scope.